# How automatically update div with live stats?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm new to the list, I need your your help to solve this problem.

Ojectif: Automatically update the div with live stats

We have a website for online ads, this site shows you the number of live connected, ad views etc ... until today I did a setInterval which launched a jquery function to update the div. This all works well, only problem that consumes unnecessary connections.
And comes nodejs, great tool .. except it kills the server. (probably because I use it wrong)

Here's how I do it:

The client side:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://10.0.0.10:1337/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function ($)
{
    if (typeof (io) != "undefined")
    {
        var socket = io.connect("http://10.0.0.10:1337/socket.io.js");
        setInterval(function ()
        {
            socket.emit("cron_showcompteur",
            {
                ssid: "*SSID_ID*",
                id_website: 1
            });
        }, 5 * 1000);

        socket.on("showinfo", function (obj)
        {
            $("#" + obj.divdest).html(obj.result);
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

The client initiates the socket every 5 seconds to cron_showcompteur with its SSID.

Server side:

```
var initConf = require('./conf');
var http = require('http');
var util = require('util');
var os = require('os');
var Memcached = require('memcached');
var memcached = new Memcached(util.format('%s:%s', initConf.objConf.memcache_ip,         initConf.objConf.memcache_port));
....

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket)
{
    socket.on('cron_showcompteur', function (obj)
    {
        var loadAvg = os.loadavg();
    if (typeof (obj.ssid) == 'undefined') return;

    socket.join(obj.ssid)
    if (loadAvg[0] < 3)
    {
        memcached.get(["nombre_visite_journee", util.format('annonces_ajoutees_journee_%d', obj.id_website)],
        function (err, result)
        {
            if (err) return;
            if (typeof (result) == 'boolean') return;

            for (var i in result)
            {
                io.sockets. in (obj.ssid).emit('showinfo',
                {
                    divdest: i,
                    result: addCommas(result[i])
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

});

In summary:

The person connects to the site, sending its SSID it with his ID website
Once initialized nodejs socket created a room with its SSID, every 5 seconds the client asks the stats and nodejs sending the result in the div using the "showinfo"

This works great when you're 600/700 connected to cons up to 1000 as soon as the server (a server dedicated to nodejs) CPU rises to 100%, the result of anything the site works no longer able to initialize the nodejs socket on the server and site plant.

I tested several variants:

- Put the setInterval server side, it is worse.
- From fonctioner to trigger as soon as a client connects or opens an ad that charging other etc ....

Memeched stats are updated on the PHP

I have a doubt about the cons made ??that we need to create a user-room, it seems big ... because the data are not private.

I would like to avoid the long-pooling, I like the idea of ??the socket.

The server was at 100% CPU past the 932 connected to nodejs

```
calou3 root @: ~ # netstat-tanpu | grep node | awk {'print $ 5'} | cut-f 1-d "" | uniq-c | sort-nnetstat-tanpu && | grep node | wc-l
```

932

Currently the server is 412 (after a reboot Node) the CPU is 3% and the avg of 0

Could you advise me a method to automatically update the DIV on all wireless clients that do not crash the server?

Thank you very much for your help (and sorry for my english)